# Jackson Filter and Deserialize from a List of Objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, json-deserialization, spring-cloud-feign

Consider I have a DTO class like below:

```java
    class MyDTO {
        Type property1;
        Type property2;
        // ... and so on
    }
```

Now I have an API that returns a list of `MyDTO` objects. But I want to filter out and get the single object `MyDTO` from this list of objects based on some criteria (say property1 == some value).

I know , I can do this by using `streams` after getting the list of objects. But is there any *Jackson* way of doing it? so that in my *Feign Client* call I can have single object as a return type.

```java
    // returns a single object after filtering 
    // for one object while serializing.
    MyDTO feignCallApi()
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Jackson is only used for serializing/deserializing data. In your scenario described, the below are 2 possibilities:

#### Option 1 - API provides filtering capabilities with e.g. query params

The API you communicate with provides a possibility to filter out the desired object using some query param.

#### Option 2 - introduce intermediary layer in your application

Introduce an intermediary layer, e.g. a service class that utilizes the client, and performs any necessary filtering on the result of the call using e.g. a stream.

`Calling class -> service class -> fiegn client`

Then the service class can still have a method that returns only 1 MyDTO object.